# AsyncTask that calls JNI Background process with update progress (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, java-native-interface

I have an `AsyncTask` that calls a native method, and I want to report the progress.
Is it possible? I can't change the Native since its a black box to me, but I can read its output which is a file, which I can parse as progress.

Thanks,
Eli

Comment: Can you not modify the JNI because you don't understand it, or are you actually forbidden from doing so?  The easiest answer to this is to set up a simple callback for this purpose.  If you can't do that I guess you have to compare the output to expected output and derive progress from there.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds rough to manage the progression with the tools available to you.

Comment: I can't modify the JNI because I don't have the native source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I know, its not possible using async task, but its doable using combination of threads and handler.

you can use this pattern:
Use a Class with 2 threads, one for the worker and one for the progress report.
The last updates the progress bar (which is a member).
When finished, call the handler message method to dismiss the progress bar.
You can grab the code from [here](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2014/03/acynctask-that-calls-jni-background.html).

Eli